# Is it possible to check this way, that all elements in 2d Array are the same?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

So I googled this question. And only this link from StackOF came up. [The question is ~4 years old.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530721/how-to-check-in-2d-array-if-all-elements-in-row-and-column-are-the-same)

I find my solution to be rather simple, but nobody wrote about it, does it make sense?

Here's the code:

```
public boolean areAllTheSame(int[][] image) {

    // Create a new set, so we can store our unique elems there.
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    //Iterate through all elements, add to our HashSet set
    for (int[] ints : image) {
        for (int anInt : ints) {
            set.add(anInt);
        }
    }
    // Because set has only unique elements, if all are the same => size should be 1

    return set.size() == 1;
} // end of areAllTheSame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```java
public boolean areAllTheSame(int[][] image) {
  // assuming `image` >= 1x1 pixels

  int expectedPixel = image[0][0];

  for (int[] pixels: image)
    for (int pixel: pixels)
      if(pixel != expectedPixel)
        return false;

  return true;
}
```

It stops looping as soon as it knows the array is not uniform, and it doesn't require the allocation of a `HashSet<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are more ways, one of them, by using java streaming :

```
public boolean areAllTheSame(int[][] image) {
    return Arrays.stream(image)
            .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
            .distinct()
            .count() == 1;
}
```

Comment: The second and third examples aren't right, because they only check whether the _rows_ are equal, and not _individual_ pixels.

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel no at all, I'm using `Arrays.equals(first, a)` which took two arrays and compare if they are equals or not

Comment: If I remember correctly, `Arrays.equals(a, b)` iterates over both arrays at the same time and checks whether `a[0] == b[0]`, `a[1] == b[1]`, and on and on, but `a[0]` might differ from `b[1]`.

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel for the second solution, you can solve it also like this `public static boolean areAllTheSame2(int[][] image) {
    int[] first = image[0];
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(first)).size() == 1
            && Arrays.stream(image).allMatch(a -> Arrays.equals(first, a));
}`

Comment: I think that would work. Now, I'd say one problem is that you have to allocate a `HashSet<Integer>`, and the loop could be optimized by stopping as soon as it finds a different pixel than the first one.

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel yes you can do it by using `!Arrays.stream(image).anyMatch(a -> !Arrays.equals(first, a));`

Comment: by the way I just stumbled on `Streams` javadoc: `anyMatch` is a short-circuiting operation: it stops iterating as soon as applying one element to the predicate returns `false`... So your previous example was already short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems very inefficient, if you want to check if a multidimensional array only contains one element you can just take the first element and then compare it to all other numbers, if a single one doesn't match you return false

Comment: @LostPuppy Do you really think I wrote this after he made his comment? When I answered there were no comments